# Searching vector using regex

Tags: c++, regex, vector

I'm trying to search values in a vector and if they match do some handling, but I've realized that the std::find implementation searches for a 100% match, so if I'm looking for "DOG" and my target string is "DOGGIE" I get nothing.

I'm wondering is there a way to combine the std::find implementation with a pattern as it's search target? Such that:

```
find = std::find(abc.begin(), abc.end(), pattern);
```

Returns as != abc.end() for the case above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to search a collection via a predicate.  You will supply the predicate and use the functions defined within the [regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) header to perform the match.

Answer (score -1):

Is [the regex library in the standard C++ library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) enough?